# Corner position and centre of pixel in NetCDF data in R

Tags: r, gis

I am having trouble trying to open NetCDF data in R. Basically, my main problem is about the centre of the pixel, which I think in my case is not the left-bottom corner but centre (or even right-upper corner, not sure). Take a look at this raster with a correctly projected administrative border:

[image]

----------------------------------------

I use this code:

To open the file:

```
  wd <- ("~/Desktop/Regionalitzacio")
    RCP85_TN_MAM<- nc_open(paste0(wd,"/rcp8.5_nc/MRE+ESTADISTICS-RCP85-sim1-TN-MAM-20212050.nc"))
```

To create the array:

```
RCP85_TN_MAM <- ncvar_get(RCP85_TN_MAM, "TMIN_rg")
```

Transforming it into raster and exporting it:

```
CRS <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs")
r <- raster(t(RCP85_TN_MAM), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS) #ed50geografic
r <- flip(r, direction='y')
writeRaster(r, "RCP85_TN_MAM", "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I made it once in ARCMAP because the software allows you to select wether your cordinates are in the bottom-left or anywhere else, but I didn't manage to find such an option in R.

**Do you know if it's possible to give R where exactly your cordinates fit?**

Answer (score 1):

To open ncdf files with raster data in R, without having to worry about georeferencing, you can do

```
wd <- "."
setwd(wd)
library(terra)
RCP85_TN_MAM <- rast("/rcp8.5_nc/MRE+ESTADISTICS-RCP85-sim1-TN-MAM-20212050.nc")
```

Or

```
library(raster)
RCP85_TN_MAM <- brick("/rcp8.5_nc/MRE+ESTADISTICS-RCP85-sim1-TN-MAM-20212050.nc"))
```